# Using Multiple Realms and Multiple Clients in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We have a use case of maintaining different organizations and respective users using Keycloak. We are trying to follow the below sequence of steps to achieve the same

1. Create a separate realm for each organization using master realm
2. Create roles for each realm
3. Create a client of each new realm
4. Create user for organization using the above client
5. Assigning roles to the user
6. Performing login/logout and other required actions

Is the above approach cleaner to maintain organizations and the respective user actions? Please help us to make it better.

Comment: "Realm - A realm manages a set of users, credentials, roles, and groups. A user belongs to and logs into a realm. Realms are isolated from one another and can only manage and authenticate the users that they control." We have faced similar approach. As described in the Keycloak docs, if you need to separate  at least  one of of them the users, groups and clients, you must use realm for each organizations. Otherwise, organizations's user, group may conflict. etc: assume there is a user who member of more than one organization.